# Замечание на sonar: "Refactor your code not to use hardcoded absolute paths or URIs."

Tags: c#, wpf, uri

Имею проблему с указанием путей к файлам в WPF приложении. Изображение приложение находит только, когда они прописаны вот так:

```
    private const string transparentImagePath = @"/ConnectorCore;component/UI/images/transparentImg.png";
    private const string greyLockImagePath = @"/ConnectorCore;component/UI/images/greyLock.png";
    private const string redLockImagePath = @"/ConnectorCore;component/UI/images/redLock.png";

    internal CheckOutFiles(Item itemIndex)
    {
        try
        {
            switch (itemIndex.getLockStatus())
            {
                case 0:
                    Locked = new Uri(transparentImagePath, UriKind.Relative);
                    break;
                case 1:
                    Locked = new Uri(greyLockImagePath, UriKind.Relative);
                    break;
                case 2:
                    Locked = new Uri(redLockImagePath, UriKind.Relative);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
     }
```

И в этом случае при анализе моего кода на Sonar выдается замечание: *"Refactor your code not to use hardcoded absolute paths or URIs."*

Я экспериментировали с указанием путей: и через "pack://application:...", и через "~/", и через указание пути без "/ConnectorCore;component"... Но тогда файлы не находятся и изображение не отображаются.

[image: На этой картинке изображено расположение класса, в котором нужно прописать пути к файлам изображений, и папки с изображениями.]

Так же была попытка прописать пути в конфиге, но почему-то возвращается 0 keys, то есть приложение не находило вообще ключей в App.config. Возможно это из-за того, что в солюшене 2 проекта.

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что нужно изменить в путях, чтобы не появлялись замечания на sonar и чтобы картинки отображались корректно.

Comment: Всё, что вам нужно сделать, это `"Refactor your code not to use hardcoded absolute paths or URIs."`- Вы это прочитали? Перевели? Поняли?

Comment: Имхо, в данном случае можно смело игнорировать этот ворнинг, ну или отключить его. У вас же изображения внутри сборки, поэтому пути не абсолютные. Ложное срабатывание инструмента.

Comment: @tym32167, да. Но как и отмечает @Андрей NOP, пути не абсолютные. Я же не указываю, что файлы лежат на диску С, в моих документах. По сути я и не `use hardcoded absolute paths or URIs`, но замечание все же есть.

Comment: @АндрейNOP спасибо)

Comment: Ага, я уже поглядел. Видимо, оно как то решило, что пути абсолютные :)